# constexpr check of a type

Tags: c++, c++14, sfinae, type-traits, template-argument-deduction

I'm trying to overload some function based on whether or not I'm passing an Eigen matrix to them, and I wanted to make myself some nice `constexpr` function to improve readability.

For that I decided to emulate the implementation of `std::is_same` given on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same

```cpp
template<class T, class U>
struct is_same : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct is_same<T, T> : std::true_type {};
```

And I told myself sure, easy enough:

```cpp
template <typename T>
bool constexpr is_eigen() { return false; }

template <typename T, typename Eigen::Matrix<typename T::Scalar,
                                             T::RowsAtCompileTime,
                                             T::ColsAtCompileTime,
                                             T::Options,
                                             T::MaxRowsAtCompileTime,
                                             T::MaxColsAtCompileTime>>
bool constexpr is_eigen() { return true; }
```

However my Eigen types resolve to the first template specialization, not the first (putting a dummy `typename U` doesn't help).

I also tried something like:

```cpp
template <typename T, bool is_it = std::is_same<T,
                                                Eigen::Matrix<typename T::Scalar,
                                                              T::RowsAtCompileTime,
                                                              T::ColsAtCompileTime,
                                                              T::Options,
                                                              T::MaxRowsAtCompileTime,
                                                              T::MaxColsAtCompileTime>>::value>
bool constexpr is_eigen() { return is_it; }

template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_class<T>::value>>
bool constexpr is_eigen() { return false; }
```

But for non-Eigen classes the first overload doesn't resolve, and trying anything to change that means Eigen will still hit the false branch

Basically, any default branch I come up with gets taken even for Eigen-types. I hate SFINAE :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use partial specialization to match a `Eigen::Matrix<...>` like so

```
template <typename T>
struct is_eigen_impl : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, int... Is>
struct is_eigen_impl<Eigen::Matrix<T, Is...>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_eigen = is_eigen_impl<T>::value;
```

Comment: `Eigen::Matrix` takes a bunch of `int`s after the first type.

Comment: @Barry Oh, I see. Not familiar with `Eigen`. Modified the answer to match a single type and a pack of `int`s.

Comment: @CruzJean I think `is_eigen` and `is_eigen_v` would make sense. It would follow the pattern of `std::is_same` for example. The type (true/fale_type) is not really relevant here, and the `_t` helpers in the standard library usually retrieves a relevant typedef/using.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that solved my issue (and saved me some frustration). Does it work because the type deduction works differently for classes than it does for functions?

Comment: @super Right, I realized my mistake after the edit period elapsed. The `_t` form is typically for the `typename whatever<T>::type` idiom.

Comment: @lesurp This works because the false version will match any type, and the true version will match only types with the pattern `Eigen::Matrix<T, Is...>`. Since the true version is more specialized, it will be preferred when applicable. As max66 shows in his answer functions can also be used. There the rule is that between overloaded templates, the most exact match to the passed in argument will be selected. The principles are very similar.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you trying to obtain something as follows (caution: code not tested)

```
template <typename T>
constexpr std::false_type is_eigen_helper (T const &);

template <typename T, int ... Is>
constexpr std::true_type is_eigen_helper (Eigen::Matrix<T, Is...> const &);

template <typename T>
constexpr auto is_eigen { decltype(is_eigen_helper(std::declval<T>()))::value };
```

In this case `is_eigen<T>` is a template variable, so is required C++14.

In C++11 you can define `is_eigen<T>` as a type

```
template <typename T>
using is_eigen = decltype(is_eigen_helper(std::declval<T>()));
```

so you can use `is_eigen<T>::value` to check if `T` is an `Eigen::Matrix`.

p.s.: template specialization, as in super's answer, is another (maybe better) way to do almost the same thing.

But, as pointed by Jarod42, there is a difference.

With my solution you obtain that `is_eigen<T>` (or `is_eigen<T>::value`, in C++11) is `true` when `T` is a `Eigen::Matrix` of some type **or** a class that inherits from some `Eigen::Matrix` class.

With super's solution you get that `is_eigen<T>::value` is `true` only if `T` is an `Eigen::Matrix`. When `T` inherit from an `Eigen::Matrix`, `is_eigen<T>` is `false`.

See you what is better for your needs.

Comment: Notice that class inherited from Eigen matrix is also considered as same in your version. So not exactly the same as super's answer.

Comment: You don't need the dummy int/long parameter here.

Comment: @Barry - because the second is a better match; you're right; thanks. I'll simplify.

Comment: Interesting solution. However we don't inherit from those classes therefore I'll stick with the other answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This question mentions C++14, but note that as of C++17 you can use `std::is_same_v` to achieve `constexpr` type equality checks.

Examples from the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same):

```
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<int, std::int32_t> << ' ';  // ~ true
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<int, std::int64_t> << '\n'; // ~ false
```